# Using onUpgrade() to create new database table SQLite Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm new to SQLite databases in Android so I need a little help. The app I'm trying to make will store the users workout exercises and reps for each exercise. I have a database set up and working that will store one exercise and it's reps but I can't get the onUpgrade() method to work so that I can create a larger database with the rest of the exercises.

The original code made a database with the following columns

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + 
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                KEY_EXERCISE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_EX1REPS1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                KEY_EX1REPS2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                KEY_EX1REPS3 +  " TEXT NOT NULL);"

                );

    }
```

But I want to add the following for example

```
                KEY_EXERCISE2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_EX2REPS1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                KEY_EX2REPS2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                KEY_EX2REPS3 + " TEXT NOT NULL);
```

I've tried doing this using the below onUpgrade method but it won't work

```
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE); 
        onCreate(db);

    }
```

If someone could tell me how to add the addition columns it would be greatly appreciated. The following is the complete database.java file.

```
public class Database {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

public static final String KEY_EXERCISE = "exercise_name";
public static final String KEY_EX1REPS1 = "exercise_rep1";
public static final String KEY_EX1REPS2 = "exercise_rep2";
public static final String KEY_EX1REPS3 = "exercise_rep3";


public static final String KEY_EXERCISE2 = "exercise2_name";
public static final String KEY_EX2REPS1 = "exercise2_rep1";
public static final String KEY_EX2REPS2 = "exercise2_rep2";
public static final String KEY_EX2REPS3 = "exercise2_rep3";


private DbHelper ourHelper; //just a insince of the DbHelper class
private final Context ourContext;
public static SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Workouts";
static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "exercisesandreps";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_EXERCISE, KEY_EX1REPS1, KEY_EX1REPS2, KEY_EX1REPS3, KEY_EXERCISE2, KEY_EX2REPS1, KEY_EX2REPS2, KEY_EX2REPS3};


private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        //context, name, factory, version
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + 
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + //each one of these lines defines a column of the database
                KEY_EXERCISE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_EX1REPS1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                KEY_EX1REPS2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                KEY_EX1REPS3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                KEY_EXERCISE2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_EX2REPS1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                KEY_EX2REPS2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                KEY_EX2REPS3 + " TEXT NOT NULL);"

                );

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE); 
        onCreate(db);

    }   
}
public Database(Context c){
    ourContext = c;
}

public Database open() throws SQLException{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase(); //use writable because if you can write to it, you can read it
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String Exercise, String Ex1R1, String Ex1R2, String Ex1R3, String Exercise2, String Ex2R1, String Ex2R2, String Ex2R3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    //String Exercise1 = convertArrayToString(ExerciseArray);

    cv.put(KEY_EXERCISE, Exercise);
    cv.put(KEY_EX1REPS1, Ex1R1);
    cv.put(KEY_EX1REPS2, Ex1R2);
    cv.put(KEY_EX1REPS3, Ex1R3);


    cv.put(KEY_EXERCISE2, Exercise2);
    cv.put(KEY_EX2REPS1, Ex2R1);
    cv.put(KEY_EX2REPS2, Ex2R2);
    cv.put(KEY_EX2REPS3, Ex2R3);

    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv); //this will crash if you haven't set up a table with rows + columns

}

public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_EXERCISE, KEY_EX1REPS1, KEY_EX1REPS2, KEY_EX1REPS3, KEY_EXERCISE2, KEY_EX2REPS1, KEY_EX2REPS2, KEY_EX2REPS3};
    //you read information through a cursor
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    //these keep track of the current row, name, hotness
    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);//position 0
    int iExercise1 = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EXERCISE);//position 1
    int iEx1R1 = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EX1REPS1);//position 2
    int iEx1R2 = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EX1REPS2);//position 3
    int iEx1R3 = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EX1REPS3);//position 4

    int iExercise2 = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EXERCISE);//position 1
    int iEx2R1 = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EX1REPS1);//position 2
    int iEx2R2 = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EX1REPS2);//position 3
    int iEx2R3 = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EX1REPS3);//position 4

    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){  //!c.isAfterLast = if our cursor is not after the last entry in our database 
        //starting at the first position, it will move one each go unless it hasn't exceeded the last entry
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iExercise1) + " " + c.getString(iEx1R1) + " " + c.getString(iEx1R2) + " " + c.getString(iEx1R3) + 
                                                    c.getString(iExercise2) + " " + c.getString(iEx2R1) + " " + c.getString(iEx2R2) + " " + c.getString(iEx2R3) + 

                "\n";

    }
    return result;
}

public String getExercise(long l) throws SQLException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_EXERCISE, KEY_EX1REPS1, KEY_EX1REPS2, KEY_EX1REPS3, KEY_EXERCISE2, KEY_EX2REPS1, KEY_EX2REPS2, KEY_EX2REPS3};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l,null, null, null, null);

    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String exercise = c.getString(1);//we know the name column is the second column in the database so it will have a position 1
        return exercise;//the code will only return the name if the cursor is set to null
    }

    return null;
}



public String[] getReps1(long l) throws SQLException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_EXERCISE, KEY_EX1REPS1, KEY_EX1REPS2, KEY_EX1REPS3};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l,null, null, null, null);

    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String reps1 = c.getString(2);//we know the name column is the second column in the database so it will have a position 1
        String reps2 = c.getString(3);
        String reps3 = c.getString(4);
        String[] result = new String[]{reps1, reps2, reps3};
        return result;//the code will only return the name if the cursor is set to null
    }
    return null;
}


public void updateEntry (long lRow, String mExercise, String mEx1Reps1, String mEx1Reps2, String mEx1Reps3) throws SQLException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_EXERCISE, mExercise);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_EX1REPS1, mEx1Reps1);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_EX1REPS2, mEx1Reps2);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_EX1REPS3, mEx1Reps3);

    ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_ROWID + "=" + lRow, null);
}

public void deleteEntry(long lRow1) throws SQLException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + lRow1, null);

}


public static String convertArrayToString(String[] array){
    String str = "";
    for (int i = 0;i<array.length; i++) {
        str = str+array[i];
        // Do not append comma at the end of last element
        if(i<array.length-1){
            str = str+",";
        }
    }
    return str;
}
public static String[] convertStringToArray(String str){
    String[] arr = str.split(",");
    return arr;
}

public void deleteAll() {
    Cursor c = getAllRows();
    long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            deleteRow(c.getLong((int) rowId));              
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
}

public Cursor getAllRows() {
    String where = null;
    Cursor c =  ourDatabase.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                        where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    return ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Increase you DATABASE_VERSION if you have not done.
2. Normally, you need to extract  `db.execSQL("....")` which in the onCreate method
   into a new method, for instance named `upgradeDB()`, then you can call
   the `upgradeDB()` method in `onUpgrade` method.

or else, you can completely uninstall you app in your device, and then re-install it, it will re-create the whole db.

Comment: Thanks for that but I still get the same error as usual:                 08-07 07:35:25.707: E/SQLiteLog(25037): (1) near "EXISTSexercisesandreps": syntax error

Comment: Well, just change to
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE); 
that is, adding a blank string after EXISTS.